# Volante para prestación

Tags: significado

Quisiera confirmar si [un volante para prestación](https://www.mutuauniversal.net/export/sites/webpublica/.content/documentos/pdfs/DM-WP-RE0614.pdf) es en realidad un volante de solicitud de servicios, significando que no se sabe todavía la fecha exacta de la prestación cuando el dicho volante acaba de ser expedido, ¿no es así“? ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En general un volante de prestación es un volante de solicitud de servicios. Por tanto, la respuesta es Sí.

En este caso, cuando el volante acaba de ser expedido no se sabe exactamente  la fecha exacta de la prestación, ya que el expediente lleva consigo una tramitación, si bien la prestación debería iniciarse desde el momento de la baja médica para las contingencias comunes. En caso de accidente o enfermedad, se produce desde el día siguiente a la baja médica.

En letra pequeña aparecen unos plazos para la tramitación del "parte" por parte de la empresa, cuando la "Mutua" considere que ha existido un accidente laboral;

• *La emisión de esta solicitud de asistencia sanitaria no supone el reconocimiento, por parte de la mutua, del incidente como laboral.*

• *En caso de que la mutua califique el incidente como **accidente de trabajo**, de acuerdo con las disposiciones legales vigentes, la empresa deberá:*

*a) **Si causa baja médica**: tramitar el correspondiente Parte de Accidente de Trabajo, **en los 5 días siguientes** a la fecha de emisión de la baja médica
o en l**as 24h siguientes** en caso de accidente grave, muy grave o fallecimiento.*

*b) **Si no causa baja médica**: incluir este proceso en la Relación de Accidentes de Trabajo Sin Baja Médica en los **cinco primeros días hábiles del
mes siguiente al de la asistencia**.*

Por tanto hay que tener en cuenta:

- La prestación se inicia desde el momento de la baja médica para las contingencias comunes. En los casos de accidente de trabajo y enfermedad profesional se produce desde el día siguiente a la baja médica.
- Independientemente del tipo de baja laboral, el día que paga la Seguridad Social las bajas es el último día hábil de cada mes. En caso de ser festivo, pasa a ser el inmediatamente anterior. Por otra parte, el día en el que se refleja este ingreso en la cuenta bancaria dependerá de cada banco.

Comment: Hola, Diego! ¡Muchísimas gracias por su respuesta, como siempre! ¿Podría Usted explicar el significado de "parte" en "Parte de Accidente de Trabajo"? ¡Muchas gracias otra vez!

Comment: ¡ Hola Maurice!, espero que te encuentres bien. ¡Gracias a ti! La palabra "parte" (dar parte), tiene varias acepciones. Así se llama "parte de baja médica" cuando el médico emite el "parte de baja", indicando la fecha de la revisión médica prevista. En estos casos puedes entender la palabra "parte" como impreso, volante, papel, documento...que se entrega a otra persona. Existe el "Parte médico" por ejemplo cuando alguien entra en un hospital o es víctima de un accidente o catástrofe. El "parte militar", por ejemplo cuando se habla de "parte de bajas" en una guerra.

Comment: También puede hablarse de "parte" para referirse a las noticias o noticiarios que dan en la radio o en la televisión en el horario habitual, aunque es un modo anticuado de hacerlo, y el usual "parte meteorológico", cuando se refieren a las noticias referidas al tiempo. Espero te haya servido. ¡Saludos!

Comment: En este caso  "Parte de Accidente de Trabajo", se refiere al anuncio o impreso del accidente de trabajo. Es el documento oficial que deberá de cumplimentar la empresa cuando se produzca un accidente de trabajo o recaída que comporte la ausencia del trabajador/a del puesto de trabajo de, como mínimo, un día, sin contar el día en que se accidentó, previa baja médica.

Comment: Cuando se produce un accidente que ocasiona baja médica de al menos un día (además del día en que ocurrió el accidente), el empresario tiene la obligación de cumplimentar el original y cuatro copias del Parte Oficial de Accidente de Trabajo y remitirlos a la "mutua" en el plazo máximo de 5 días hábiles.

Comment: La empresa debe notificar por escrito a la Autoridad Laboral de la provincia correspondiente el accidente de trabajo que haya ocurrido, a través del Sistema de Declaración Electrónica de Accidentes de Trabajo en un plazo de 5 días.

Comment: El plazo para la cumplimentación del parte de accidente de trabajo es de cinco días hábiles desde la fecha en que ocurrió el accidente o desde la fecha de baja médica.

Comment: Wow ~ ¡Muchas gracias por haberme explicado el significado de "parte" con tanto detalle, Diego! Me encuentro bien y espero que a Usted también. ¡Le deseo un muy buen fin de semana!